# Working with a List of Lists as a Class in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created the following class to organize some variables that I need to save to a text file:

```
public class ListOfVariablesToSave : List<List<Tuple<string, int, string>>>
{
    public List<Tuple<string, int, string>> control { get; set;}
    public List<Tuple<string, int, string>> interaction { get; set;}

    public ListOfVariablesToSave()
    {
        control = new List<Tuple<string, int, string>>
        {
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDC/MCSTEP", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDC/NCSTEP", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDC/DCSTEC", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDC/DCTIME", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDC/ICOUTF", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDC/ICSHTF", 0, "")
        };

        interaction = new List<Tuple<string, int, string>>
        {
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDI/MICOUP", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDI/NICOUP", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDI/DIEZON", 0, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDI/I1IECN", 1, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDI/I1IECT", 1, ""),
            Tuple.Create("/YD/YDI/MISTATE", 0, "")
        };
    }
}
```

However, when I create an instance with:

```
ListOfVariablesToSave myListOfVariablesToSave = 
    new ListOfVariablesToSave();
```

I get the list with no elements (count = 0).In particular, when I try to access the list with the following code:

```
foreach (List<Tuple<string, int, string>> DB in myListOfVariablesToSave)
{
    foreach (Tuple<string, int, string> varToSave in DB)
    {
        // DO SOMETHING.
    }
}
```

nothing happens because the (outer) list is empty. What am I missing? How do I access the lists inside my outer list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you inherited the list, but you did not put anything into it in the constructor. If you would like the two items that you created to become available, add these two lines to the end of your constructor:

```
Add(control);
Add(interaction);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was the problem.